# What is the difference between using/(not using) MATCH in a MERGE query in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When creating a probably existing node in neo4j, i'm getting confused about the use of `MATCH`. What would be the difference between these two cases?

1.-
`MERGE (n:Person { user_id: 1234 ,sex:'male'})`

2.- `MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.user_id = 1234 AND a.sex = 'male' MERGE (n:Person { user_id: 1234 ,sex:'male'})`

Actually even after reading the documentation I can't understand the usefullness of `MATCH`

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is "get or create". If the pattern exists, get it (bind to the variables specified). If the pattern specified does not exist, then create it.

`MATCH` is just "get". If the pattern exists, bind to the variables specified. If the pattern does not exist, then nothing is bound to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the differences between your 2 queries.

- Query #1 will create a node with the specified label and properties if and only if such a node is not found.
- Query #2 is basically a waste of time. It calls `MATCH` to look for a node with the specified label and properties, and only if it is found does it call `MERGE` (which would create the node if and only if it does not already exist). So, #2 ends up never making any changes. If the node already existed, it will continue to exist (since `MERGE` will discover it doesn't need to do anything). If it did not exist, it will remain nonexistent (since `MERGE` would not even be invoked).

Needless to say, one would never want to use `MATCH` and `MERGE` in the same way as #2. Here is a more typical example of `MATCH` and `MERGE`, which ensures that the `SPOUSE_OF` relationship exists between 2 people who are already in the DB:

```
MATCH (a:Person {user_id: 1234}), (b:Person {user_id: 5678})
MERGE (a)-[:SPOUSE_OF]->(b);
```